# How to resize the images to have the same height in group while keeping aspect ratio?

Tags: javascript, css, semantic-ui

Currently, take a look at list of products with images:

[image]

Notice these pics are different sizes like different width and different height, I don't want it look bad, I'm looking a solution how to resize them properly without bothering aspect ratio. Excepted result would be like that:

[image]

There is CSS snippet for each img

```
   .ui.medium.image
   {
        width: 300px;
        height: auto;
        font-size: 1rem;
   }
```

If I change height: auto to height: 200px, but it ruins aspect ratio:

[image]

How to fix them properly with same height while keeping aspect ratio?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just set the width to auto, this will make them all the same height, and preserve the aspect ratio. However, they will then be different widths:

```
   .ui.medium.image
   {
        width: auto;
        height: 200px;
        font-size: 1rem;
   }
```

The best way to do this would be to use a background-image instead.
e.g.:

```
.ui.medium.image {
  /*Image should be a div*/
  height: 200px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Then, you could just set the image with an inline style:

```
<div class="image" style="background-image:url('path/to/image.jpg');">
```

Comment: I was thinking this with a background of a certain minimum width/height to "pad" images with a smaller width.

Comment: downvoters care to comment? If you have a problem with my answer, please post :)

Comment: Hey @JacobGray I've tested your 2 methods:


First Method, it returns the images as:
http://i.imgur.com/G7OuLxR.png  :(

Second Method:
http://i.imgur.com/sAkEL5l.png :(

Comment: @ivan in the second method, remove the width style

Comment: @JacobGray That's better http://i.imgur.com/aLVmIxv.png any suggestions to make it look better? I consider this answer may be accepted

Comment: @JacobGray Please edit your question so I can accept it, it seems enough

Comment: Downvoters care to comment? If you see something wrong with my answer, you should address it, or else your downvote is meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

You need to center and crop the images using CSS background images.

```
<style>
    .image {
        background-position: center;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        float: left;
    }
</style>

<div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/');"></div>
<div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/300/500/abstract/');"></div>
<div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/400/nature/');"></div>
```

Comment: Try the divs with background images like in my example.

Comment: Yes, I exactly copied these divs as your example, maybe if affects "pad" where is inside of picture

Comment: It looks like you are still using image tags and not background images. Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/np157L57/ – Yes. You will want to use margins instead of padding as padding will show the background images.

Comment: I didn't use <img> I already replace them as <div> with your example, still have same issue as I posted gif